# bootstrap col using max width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

is there a way to use the bootstrap column system and max width at the same time using 100% of the page width?

There is an example of that i'm trying to do here:

https://jsfiddle.net/0e1nLun0/2/

```css
.box-one{
  background-color: red;
  max-width: 200px;
}
.box-two{
  background-color: green;
}
.box-three{
  background-color: red;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 box-one">
      <p>Test box one</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 box-two">
      <p>Test box two</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 box-three">
      <p>Test box three</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

After the 3rd box there is a white space and that's normal, but is there a way for the second box(the green one) to increase its width so there won't be any white space?
The goal is that the second box is still responsive.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: sorry it was a mistake

Comment: Sounds like you need flexbox and Bootstrap 4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you should use a `col` in a `row`, and a `row` in a `container` or `container-fluid`.

When having that, change the row to `display:flex;` and let your `col-6` grow using `flex-grow: 1;`

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.col-md-6 {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.box-one {
  background-color: red;
  max-width: 200px;
}

.box-two {
  background-color: green;
}

.box-three {
  background-color: red;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 box-one">
      <p>Test box one</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 box-two">
      <p>Test box two</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 box-three">
      <p>Test box three</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ofcourse, to have this working responsively, you need some additional work.

Another way is upgrade to Bootstrap 4, which grid is built with flexbox.